# проблема с foreach и записью в бд

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Здравствуйте! хочу что бы при каждом поподении в бд создавалась новая стока для файла, помогите второй день мучаюсь

```html
 $error_list = implode(',', $error_list);
    $success_list = implode(',', $success_list);
    $success_list_small = implode(',', $success_list_small);
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/bd.php');
    $sqlimage .= "INSERT INTO images_big(id, catalog, filename, catalog_small, filename_small) 
        VALUES foreach($success_list as $success_lists){ 
            $sqlimage .=("'.$id.'"
               ,"'.$uploads_dir.'"
               ,"'.$success_lists.'"
               ,"'.$uploads_dir_smale.'"
               ,"'.$success_list_small.'")
        }";
    $sqlimage.=implode(',',$array);
    $stmtimg = $pdo->query($sqlimage);
    $stmtimg->execute();
```

Comment: Некого не смутило что у него цикл в запросе?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Генерировать SQL-запрос таким образом является крайне плохой практикой. Более правильно сначала подготовить запрос и выполнять каждый INSERT отдельно

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO images_big(id, catalog, filename, catalog_small, filename_small) 
    VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");

$id = $_GET['id']; //Ничего, что у них у всех id будет одинаковый?
$catalog = '/какая/то/директория';
$catalog_small = 'директория';
$success_list = [массив какой-то];
$success_list_small = [другой массив, но элементов столько же, сколько в $success_list ];

$stmt->bindParam(1,$id,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(2,$catalog,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(3,$filename,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(4,$catalog_small,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(5,$filename_small,PDO::PARAM_STR);

for($i=0;$i<count($success_list);$i++){
    $filename=$success_list[$i];
    $filename_small=$success_list_small[$i];
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49425/discussion-on-answer-by-rjhdby---foreach----).